# Formatting a Hard Drive with WIndows 7 Machine vs. Window XP

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, ntfs

What advantages (if any) are there to formatting an external hard drive with a Windows 7 machine vs. a Windows XP machine?  The hard drive will be used for archiving files from both machines.  Will formatting in Windows 7 make the drive more resilient to errors?

Comment: Will you be formatting with NTFS or Fat32?

Comment: I will be formatting with NTFS.

Answer (score 2):

Not a bit of difference or benefit, although there are a few more options available in DISKPART in Windows 7 that may help you with partitioning the drive.

You may not be given an option, but please consider formatting with the NTFS file system.

Avoid formatting with FAT32 if you will be archiving files larger than 4GB, or more than 4 Million files, as [FAT32 has specific limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938432.aspx)

In regard to NTFS: NTFS 3.1 was released with Windows XP in autumn 2001 and is the version used with Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, and Windows 7

The NTFS.sys version number (e.g. v5.0 in Windows 2000) should not be confused with the NTFS format version number (v3.1 since Windows XP).

Windows Vista implemented Transactional NTFS, NTFS symbolic links, partition shrinking and self-healing. All except NTFS symbolic links are operating system's features. Windows Vista also introduced persistent shadow copies for use with System Restore and Previous Versions features. Persistent shadow copies, however, are deleted when an older operating system mounts that NTFS volume. This happens because the older operating system does not understand the newer format of persistent shadow copies